# Visual Source Safe 8 on Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, visual-sourcesafe

I have fairly large legacy (read only) VSS 8 database that is currently sitting on a windows 2003 server.

As part of an infrastructure consolidation I am being asked to move it onto a new Windows 2012 server. I can't find any notes on whether or not VSS8 will run on 2012; before I even attempt this do you know of any issues running VSS on Windows 2012?

Is it easier to flip the old server to a VM and keep it for posterity and those rare occasions we want to know what someone did in the naughties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the weeks since asking have deploying VSS2005 (with the runtime available on the server) onto Windows 2012 enterprise. The applications install with a warning about versions but they run fine; including the admin tools for users and checking the consistency of the databases. The end user side all works well too.

Answer (score 1):

The database itself is merely a fileshare, so you don't have to install the accelerator if you don't want to/are unable to.

Comment: Thanks; will build a test server and check if the app / web services run on the site ok.